# PermissionError: [WinError 5] subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess

These 2 lines of code give me `PermissionError: [WinError 5]`:

```
path = r'C:\\Users\\danil\\"Google Drive"\\Python3\\"Youtube API 2.0"\\GUI\\programmi\\phase.exe'
subprocess.call([path])
```

I've already tried to execute it by cmd and powershell and i don't get any problem, even not as administrator

Comment: Why do you have quotes around "Google Drive" and "Youtube API 2.0"?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue yesterday by using

```
subprocess.call([path])
```

then I tried the below and it worked

```
subprocess.run(path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

Hope it can help

Answer (score -1):

1) Open your IDE with Admin rights or move the folder from C drive to other drive.
2) Add your script and the exe to exclusion list of your antivirus if you trust it.

Comment: Still getting the `PermissionError: [WinError 5]:` trying both the solution

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the double quotes around a couple of your path components?
Oh and since you're already using the `r` prefix, you don't need to double the backslashes.

```
path = r'C:\Users\danil\Google Drive\Python3\Youtube API 2.0\GUI\programmi\phase.exe'
subprocess.call([path])
```